# I don't seem to have blur node, using v2.69

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, blur

Following along in tutorials I see the blur filter being used. I am using Blender 2.69 and I can't locate it visually or even with a search. Actually, there is no "Filters" category at all.

Do I have to download something to get it?

Comment: Are you sure you choose the right "node tree type" (3 buttons at the bottom) ? I think the Blur node is only available in compositor nodes...

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I am somewhat new to blender and didn't even know about the other two node editors. I did find it but now i need to find out how I use those other editors.

Comment: If you do a bit of web research, you can find things like that : http://viralvideos.mobi/video/1LRDR0WAneE/Blender-For-Noobs----BASIC-introduction-to-the-Node-Editor.html

Answer (score 2):

The "Blur" node is only available in "compositing" node tree type. The type can be chosen at the bottom menu-bar of the Node Editor window.

The 3 little icons correspond to the 3 node tree types available :

- Shader nodes (for materials)
- Compositing nodes
- Texture nodes

[image: Node Editor tree types]

Answer (score -3):

I have it: (I have 2.7 but with 2.69 I had it too)

[image]

I am *Compositing* mode (shown in the upper bar on the screenshot), and I checked *Use Node*, it's hidden on the screenshot, but it's just next to *Free Unused*, in the bar in the middle of the screen.

Then *Add* and it should be there!

Comment: "compositing" mode is not showed at the top, it's in the bottom menubar of the Node Editor window (the second icon right after the sphere one).