# blender filter nodes not visible

Tags: node-editor

I am new to blender. And want know how to get the filter nodes in 2.71. I'm tired of trying. In my copy of blender filter nodes are not visible. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You mean *Composite nodes*? Click on the editor menu and select the node editor (1), then ensure that composite nodes are selected (2), or press Ctrl left arrow. Screenshot: http://www.pasteall.org/pic/78133.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14425/nodes-not-visible-for-material-created-in-properties-panel and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7854/i-dont-seem-to-have-blur-node-using-v2-69

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need to switch the tree type to compositing nodes

[image]