# Can't find the glow node

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor

I am trying to add glow to windows on a spaceship design. however, I cannot find anywhere half of the nodes I am seeing online, such as glare or glow. I have textures on my model but turning to cycle render turns it into a particle mess, and I have no idea what 'cycle renders means'. my question: can I find the right nodes in standard Blender Render mode? if not, how do I retain my previous model render look in Cycles Render?

Comment: What is your question about, compositing or switching between render engines? The latter will mean you will need to convert all the materials e.g. from BI to Cycles into the ones required by the render engine (mostly manually). As to compositing you don't provide any information about what are you doing, probably it's something like not enabled compositing nodes. Probably related -https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7854/i-dont-seem-to-have-blur-node-using-v2-69 (same for Glare node)

Comment: I think you should probably start with some basic beginner tutorials first, you are confusing far too many different concepts. *Glow* and *Glare* are compositing nodes and have nothing to do with what render engine you use. Also you can't switch renders mid production, nor make it just "look the same".

Answer (score 2):

The node editor window has three basic options:

[image]

The nodes you need are in the  compositing mode.[image]

There is no need to switch to cycles to access the compositor.

Please read: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/node_editor/